# Electron : Error on generating Setup for Windows with electron-winstaller on MacOsx

Tags: electron, macos-catalina, electron-packager, squirrel.windows

Since I'm using Catalina I'm not able to generate new nupkg and setup.exe with electron-winstaller.
I think it's a permission problem but I don't know how to resolve it.

Hope someone could help me.
Thanks.

The error that appears just after the creation of the nupkg :

```
2020-01-31 17:01:53> ReleasePackage: No release notes found in /Users/univrstudio/.local/share/SquirrelTemp/tempa/univr-store.nuspec
2020-01-31 17:01:54> Utility: Failed to extract file /Users/univrstudio/Documents/Launcher/release/univr-store-0.0.52-full.nupkg to /Users/univrstudio/.local/share/SquirrelTemp/tempa
```

```
No dice: Failed with exit code: 255
Output:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. () ---> System.Exception
  at Squirrel.Utility.CreateZipFromDirectory (System.String zipFilePath, System.String inFolder) [0x00119] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <6e26a535bf76467f9082042847cb7d56>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <6e26a535bf76467f9082042847cb7d56>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <6e26a535bf76467f9082042847cb7d56>:0 
  at Squirrel.ReleasePackage.CreateReleasePackage (System.String outputFile, System.String packagesRootDir, System.Func`2[T,TResult] releaseNotesProcessor, System.Action`1[T] contentsPostProcessHook) [0x001f7] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
  at Squirrel.Update.Program.Releasify (System.String package, System.String targetDir, System.String packagesDir, System.String bootstrapperExe, System.String backgroundGif, System.String signingOpts, System.String baseUrl, System.String setupIcon, System.Boolean generateMsi, System.String frameworkVersion, System.Boolean generateDeltas) [0x00214] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
  at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine (System.String[] args) [0x004a2] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
  at Squirrel.Update.Program.main (System.String[] args) [0x00082] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
  at Squirrel.Update.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception
  at Squirrel.Utility.CreateZipFromDirectory (System.String zipFilePath, System.String inFolder) [0x00119] in <a5ee691170b94c488950c75951ce1ba3>:0 <---
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find any solution for this?